# How to pass input text value as portlet param

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, portlet

I have a portlet page:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0" prefix="portlet" %>

<portlet:defineObjects />

<portlet:resourceURL var="resourceUrl">
    <portlet:param name="startDate" value="" />
</portlet:resourceURL>

<input id="startdateexportaging" type="text" />

<a style="font-size: 15px;" href="${resourceUrl}" >URL</a>
```

How to pass the content of `startdateexportaging` as *portlet param* `startDate` when clicking the link with `resourceUrl`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an `onclick` handler to add the content to the URL as soon the link is clicked. But that would be cumbersome, error prone and not necessary.

Instead you should add your `input` to a `form` and define the URL as action parameter:

```
<aui:form action="<%= resourceUrl.toString() %>" method="get"> 
    <aui:input name="startDate" type="text" />
<aui:button value="Download" type="submit" />
</aui:form>
```

(if you don't use AUI - you can use simple HTML tags as well)

Another advantage of this solution: A button instead of a link makes it easier for the user to understand that the content from the text field is submitted. Compare it with the use of links and buttons here on SO - if you enter some information you have to hit a button.

And it is easier for search engines to parse the website, as those try to follow links - but ignore buttons.